# Ошибка при подключении к ejabberd серверу

Tags: spring, xmpp, camel

Есть приложение Spring-Camel, на локальном хосте настроен ejabber сервер версии 18.06, пытаюсь присоединиться к чату, выдает ошибку: `Could not establish connection to XMPP server: localhost:5222/null`

Код camel:

```
from("direct:requestA")
    .log("Camel body: ${body}")
    .to("xmpp://camel@localhost:5222/chat@localhost?password=123");
```

При этом, с помощью библиотеки smack подключение происходит и сообщения посылаются.

Стек трейс ошибки:
Caused by: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: '127.0.0.1:5222' failed because: localhost/127.0.0.1 exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException.from(SmackException.java:278) ~[smack-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:620) ~[smack-tcp-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:895) ~[smack-tcp-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:409) ~[smack-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.xmpp.XmppEndpoint.createConnection(XmppEndpoint.java:182) ~[camel-xmpp-2.23.0.jar:2.23.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.xmpp.XmppPrivateChatProducer.doStart(XmppPrivateChatProducer.java:116) ~[camel-xmpp-2.23.0.jar:2.23.0]
    ... 29 common frames omitted

Comment: Какую версию camel вы используете ?

Comment: @c0ld версия camel - 2.23.0

Comment: Это runtime ошибка camel, а стектрейс и сама ошибка SmackException есть ?

Comment: @c0ld добавил в вопросе